# Xamarin Forms ListView SelectedItem binding does not appear to work

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, viewmodel, selecteditem

I have the following XAML for my ListView

```
                    <ListView x:Name="lvListItems" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
                  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  Margin="0,20,0,0"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ItemSelected="lvListItems_ItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label x:Name="lblItemName" Text="{Binding Value}" FontSize="Medium" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>                    
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

In my code behind I set the binding context as follows:

```
  this.BindingContext = ViewModelObjects.DayOfWeek;
  lvListItems.ItemsSource = ViewModelObjects.DayOfWeek.GBSDaysOfWeek_ForList;
```

In my ViewMdoel the Selected property does call the OnPropertyChanged event

```
    public GBSDayOfWeek_ForList Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return iobj_SelectedGBSDayOfWeek_ForList;
        }

        set
        {
            iobj_SelectedGBSDayOfWeek_ForList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the selected item is not indicated in the list when it displays.  Any suggestions on how to get this to work?  I know it is calling the Selected property of my ViewModel and that the correct item is being return.

UPDATE: I am going to upload a sample that illustrates the problem.  You can see that I am setting the selected value in the view model and if you set breakpoints on the Get for the property you can see it is called twice, one returning null and one returning the correct item from the list.

If I set the selected value in the OnAppearing event of the page, it seems to work.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Link to sample project:
https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ams6cZUzaeQy289UiBx0qNqH86YbHg

Comment: is **this** in your code bind a Page or a view ?

Comment: this in c# simply refers to the current object - i.e. the page.  So yes this is always defined in any C# code behind.  As I indicated everything works except the indication of which item is selected.

Comment: What do you mean by "The problem is that the selected item is not indicated in the list when it displays."? Could you explain more on the behavior you are seeing, and what you are expecting?

Comment: There is no indication in the ListView as to which item is currently selected when the list first displays.  To the best of my knowledge the text of the selected item should be a shade of blue just as if I had tapped on one of the entries.

Comment: can you share complete solution to reproduce?

Comment: anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Added a sample in the problem text.